# What XCode version do I need for mcOS HighSierra Version 10.13.6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, macos-high-sierra

Hello I have a macbook air 2017 macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6 and I tried installing from app store XCode and it says : Xcode can`t be installed on "Macintosh HD" because macOS version 10.15.2 or later is required. What can I do ? Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The current release of xcode is 11.5.1 (i think). Xcode 11.0 - 11.3 requires Mojave, Xcode 11.4.1 and above requires Catalina, so you would need to either update your OS or download Xcode 10 (probably Xcode 10.1).

There are a few potential issues with this...

1. There is a known issue that xcode 10 has trouble extracting/installing, if i remember rightly its to do with its signing certificate, you need to adjust the date on your system to unpack and install it
2. All new apps uploaded to the store must be built using Xcode 11
3. By installing and developing against an older version you will misss out on new features, such as SwiftUI which is usable since ios 13 / XC 11

Answer (score 1):

High Sierra supports Xcode 10.1. Apple provides links to older versions of Xcode here: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode

If you have successfully downloaded Xcode from the App Store in the past from your App Store account, it will be listed under your "purchased" list. If you download it from that list, it will automatically get the latest version supported by your OS.

If you haven't installed it from the App Store before, the only way you can get it there is using the latest OS version.